# PHP code after IF not executed

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

I have this function

```
public function logout() {
    if ($this -> user_model -> is_logged() === TRUE) {

        $user_id = $this -> user_model -> get_id();

        if (get_cookie('cookie_name') != FALSE) {

            delete_cookie('cookie_name');

            $new_cookie = md5(sha1(rand() . time() . $user_id));

            $this -> db -> set('cookie', $new_cookie);

            $this -> db -> update('users') -> where('id = ' . "'" . $user_id . "'");
        }

        $this -> session -> unset_userdata('user_id');

        echo "logged out? <a href=" . base_url() . ">click here</a>";
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }

}
```

when

```
if (get_cookie('cookie_name') != FALSE) {
```

is true and the code inside the if brackets is executed then the other two lines of code:

```
   $this -> session -> unset_userdata('user_id');

   echo "logged out? <a href=" . base_url() . ">click here</a>";
```

While when the if code doesn't get executed these lines are executed correctly.

The code inside if is correctly executed because then the cookie is deleted and the database updated.

I'm using Codeigniter 2.1.0 but I don't think the issue is releated to this.

My php version is 5.3 under localhost on Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your problem. When the inner If Statement is executed the following two lines of code do not execute properly? Is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: Is it possible `update` has a fatal error or an `exit` or something at the end?  How about `unset_userdata`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can chain the db commands like you are. Move the where clause to its on db call... $this->db->where("") and then run your $this->db->update(). Again, I'm not sure this is incorrect I've just never seen it done this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented above, your updates statement needs to be seperated out. You need to chage this line:

```
$this -> db -> update('users') -> where('id = ' . "'" . $user_id . "'");
```

to this:

```
$this->db->where('id = ' . "'" . $user_id . "'"); 
$this->db->update('users');
```

Be aware that the where clause is "emptied" after the update statement and if you plan on doing more than one update in the future then you will have to repeat the where clause.

Comment: that's the problem but it's strange, for other types of query it works and the query is correctly executed but then probably it fail for some reason. As you can read here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html method chaining is avalaible since php5 and it worket well for select up to now

Comment: for example this work             $this -> db -> set('activation_code', 'activated');

            $this -> db -> update('users') -> where('activation_code = ' . "'" . $code . "'");

Comment: just to clarify where must be before update. Try this: $this->db->where(‘id, $id)->update(’page’, $data);

Comment: I would make sure the "where" portion of that last clause is being executed correctly. It might be preforming the update and ignoring the "where" portion. Like I said I've never seen that before. I think I'll play with it this weekend and comment back on what I find out. Glad it fixed your problem.